# How many ways to call dependent and independent variables?

Tags: reference-request, nonexpert

The words "dependent variables" and "independent variables" are the cornerstones of every regression. However, I am collecting the alternative ways to call these two terms. Because in a paper, these words will be repeated a lot of times so I want to know more about that.

What I know so far is:

**dependent variables**: regressand

**independent variables**: regressors, [covariates](https://methods.sagepub.com/reference/encyc-of-research-design/n85.xml)

> A variable is a covariate if it is related to the dependent variable.
> According to this definition, any variable that is measurable and
> considered to have a statistical relationship with the dependent
> variable would qualify as a potential **covariate**

Comment: 'output' (dependent) and 'input' (independent) variables. 'Features' in machine learning. In machine learning, features are individual independent variables that act like a input in your system.

Comment: Sometimes 'endogenous' and 'exogenous' ...

Comment: I rarely see "endogenous" and "exogenous" as independent and dependent variables in finance paper...

Comment: There are some possible synonyms listed in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_and_independent_variables#Statistics_synonyms), although the qualification about context should be borne in mind.

Comment: That's great, thanks @AdamBailey